# Reading set of large log files line by line and count how many hostnames appear on each line

Tags: python, dataframe, large-files

I have around 300 log files in a directory and each log file contains around 3300000 lines. I need to read through each file line by line and count how many hostnames that appear on each line.I wrote basic code for that task. but it takes more than 1 hour to run and takes lots of memory as well. how can improve this code to make it run faster?

```
import pandas as pd
import gzip

directory=os.fsdecode("/home/scratch/mdsadmin/publisher_report/2018-07-25")#folder with 300 log files
listi=os.listdir(directory)#converting the logfiles into a list

for file in listi:#taking eaching log file in the list 
    tt=os.path.join(directory,file)# joining log file name along with the directory path
    with gzip.open(tt,'rt') as f: #unzipping the log file           
        rows=[]#clearing the list after every loop
        for line in f: #reading each line in the file 
            s=len(line.split('|'))
            a=line.split('|')[s-3]
            b=a.split('/')[0] #slicing just the hostname out of each line in the log file                
            if len(b.split('.'))==None:
                ''
            else:
                b=b.split('.')[0]
            rows.append(b) # appending it to a list

    df_temp= pd.DataFrame(columns=['hostname'],data=rows) #append list to the dataframe after every file is read
    df_final=df_final.append(df_temp,ignore_index=True) #appending above dataframe to a new one to avoid overwriting
    del df_temp #deleting temp dataframe to clear memory
df_rows1=df_rows1.groupby(["serverMonitoringAppCode"]).size().reset_index(name="Topic_Count") #doing the count
```

**Sample log lines**

```
tx:2018-05-05T20:44:37:626 BST|rx:2018-05-05T20:44:37:626 BST|dt:0|**wokpa22**.sx.sx.com/16604/#001b0001|244/5664|2344|455
tx:2018-05-05T20:44:37:626 BST|rx:2018-05-05T20:44:37:626 BST|dt:0|**wokdd333**.sc.sc.com/16604/#001b0001|7632663/2344|342344|23244
```

**Desired output**

[image: Desired output]

Comment: If the code works and you just want to optimize it, you may be better off asking on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: thanks :) ya it does work but takes more than an hour. just wanted to know what kind of changes should i be making in order to make it run faster.